# Matrices in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix

Since I am quite new with Swift, I was reading about Subscripts in Swift. It gave this example under Subscript Options: [theExample](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH16-ID305)

My question is how is the formula, grid[(row * columns) + column], is suppose to correspond to the right value in the grid array because when I calculate it it corresponds to the wrong value. Somebody please help.

Comment: What are your values for row, columns, and column, what is result do you get and what result to you expect? *"It corresponds to the wrong value"* is too vague

Answer (score 0):

```
     0   1   2   3   4
   --------------------
0 |  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,
1 |  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,
2 | 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
```

You have `columns = 5`.

If you want to get **8**, `row = 1` and `column = 3`.

```
row * columns + column
1 * 5 + 3 = 8.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem was that I got confused with the variables column and columns.